# Can't get some parameters from URL - returns NaN/null

Tags: javascript

I have this simple string:

```
var url_string = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGjBAYgBAZgBMcIBCndpbmRvd3MgMTDIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=2a2d61dc6122c8a17b369733693bc965;checkin_month=5&checkin_monthday=17&checkin_year=2018&checkout_month=6&checkout_monthday=1&checkout_year=2018&class_interval=1&dest_id=-90115&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=3&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&offset=0&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Ni%C5%A1&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Ni%C5%A1&ssne_untouched=Ni%C5%A1&'
```

which I got from

```
var url_string = window.location.href;

var url = new URL(url_string);
```

that is an address that currently I am on. And now I want to extract some parameters

```
var no_rooms = url.searchParams.get("no_rooms"); // 1

var group_children = url.searchParams.get("group_children"); // 0

var checkin_month = url.searchParams.get("checkin_month"); // NaN
```

How is it possible that `checkin_month`, a parameter that exists in a string, and it is a number, prints `NaN`? What am I missing here?

EDIT:
I replaced the `;` in a string with `?` using

```
url_string.replace(/;/g, "?");
```

And repeated the same process, and when I got to the

```
var checkin_month = url.searchParams.get("checkin_month"); // I got null
```

EDIT2:
I was replacing with `?` when I should replace with `&`.

Comment: Query parameters should be separated by ampersands (`&`), but some of yours are separated with semi-colons. EG, in your url: `... sid=2a2d61dc6122c8a17b369733693bc965;checkin_month=5 ...`, note the semicolon before `checkin_month`.

Comment: Oh yeah, good catch. So I can't use this `seachParams.get()` method then? Should I slice the string? @CRice

Comment: No need to slice or do other things, as @CRice said, just replace semicolon with ampersand.And then you can use your searchParams method.

Comment: Otherwise, `url.searchParams.get('label').split(';').find(e => e.contains('checkin_month')).split('=')[1]`

Comment: Edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the url is not formatted, so two way to go.

**Solution 1:**

Replace `;` with `&` to make it query parameter.

```js
var url_string = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGjBAYgBAZgBMcIBCndpbmRvd3MgMTDIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=2a2d61dc6122c8a17b369733693bc965;checkin_month=5&checkin_monthday=17&checkin_year=2018&checkout_month=6&checkout_monthday=1&checkout_year=2018&class_interval=1&dest_id=-90115&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=3&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&offset=0&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Ni%C5%A1&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Ni%C5%A1&ssne_untouched=Ni%C5%A1&'

var newUrlString = url_string.replace(/;/g, '&');
var url = new URL(newUrlString);
var checkin_month = url.searchParams.get("checkin_month");
console.log("checkin_month is " + checkin_month);
```

**Solution 2:**
Parse the string from your existing URL object

```js
var url_string = 'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.html?label=gen173nr-1DCAEoggJCAlhYSDNYBGjBAYgBAZgBMcIBCndpbmRvd3MgMTDIAQzYAQPoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=2a2d61dc6122c8a17b369733693bc965;checkin_month=5&checkin_monthday=17&checkin_year=2018&checkout_month=6&checkout_monthday=1&checkout_year=2018&class_interval=1&dest_id=-90115&dest_type=city&dtdisc=0&from_sf=1&group_adults=3&group_children=0&inac=0&index_postcard=0&label_click=undef&no_rooms=1&offset=0&postcard=0&raw_dest_type=city&room1=A%2CA%2CA&sb_price_type=total&src=index&src_elem=sb&ss=Ni%C5%A1&ss_all=0&ssb=empty&sshis=0&ssne=Ni%C5%A1&ssne_untouched=Ni%C5%A1&'
var url = new URL(url_string);
var checkin_month = url.searchParams.get('label').split(';').find(e => e.includes('checkin_month')).split('=')[1] 
console.log("checkin_month is " + checkin_month)
```

Comment: Thank you for both of your solutions. It was my small mistake that led me to EDIT the post for the first time.